The probability interval of the difference between two random variables
Suppose X1 and X2 are two random variables, where X1 has a 95% probability of being within the interval [L1, R1], and X2 has a 95% probability of being within the interval [L2, R2]. Does this imply that the difference X1 - X2 will have more than a 95% probability of lying within the interval [L1 - R2, R1 - L2]? Additionally, X1 and X2 may be either dependent or independent.
(1) Could someone clarify whether the probability bound applies in this case? Or a counterexample for this statement.
(2) If there is a counterexample, is there any additional condition that can be added to make this true?

Draw a diagram of the Cartesian coordinates $(X_1,X_2).$ The interval endpoints dissect it into nine regions.  Interpret your question in terms of probabilities within subsets of these regions.  Counterexamples are then easy to find.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks whuber. I tried many cases where X1 and X2 are from different distributions but still could not find a counterexample. It seems it holds for most of the time, but I don't know what is additional conditions for this to be true.

The first case I tried following whuber's suggestion immediately yielded a counterexample for the dependent case (one where the last probability was definitely a good bit smaller than 95%). You may be unconsciously choosing cases that would tend to confirm your belief rather than constructing an example that would disconfirm it.

Thanks for those helpful comments. Could anyone provide an exact example that I can try to calculate and validate?

I wouldn't be so quick to abandon thinking yet. Consider what subsets of those regions are relevant to the tails of the interval for the difference.

... specifically draw the boundary of the regions relevant for the interval for the difference on the diagram so you can see what subsets of those regions you would need to play with.

This is not a full answer to the question but elaborates on the hints for finding a counterexample.
whuber suggested:

Draw a diagram of the Cartesian coordinates (X1,X2).
The interval endpoints dissect it into nine regions. Interpret your question in terms of probabilities within subsets of these regions.

I then suggested focusing on which particular subsets of those regions might be relevant for intervals for the difference, by also drawing on the lines related to the interval for $X_1-X_2$, which form diagonal lines across the 9 regions.
These three sets of lines form boundaries that mark off areas that will be inside and outside each of the intervals, and the subregions they mark off are where you need to focus your attention.
There are 17 such regions/subregions, of which only a few will be relevant to attaining the goal of a counterexample.
It's a relatively straightforward matter to see which subregions to focus on.

I'll add more detail later but I don't wish to pre-empt the opportunity to think it through.
(Now a few days have gone by, adding that detail.)
Directly following those suggestions, the illustration below should be sufficient to make it clear how to construct a counterexample, by putting probability in the red parts. All that remains is allocating suitable probabilities to the triangles, with the remainder going in the center, so as to satisfy the conditions while making a counterexample.


Thanks so much for drawing the graph and providing the hint. Sorry I may not get why the diagonal line corresponds to interval for X1 - X2

This is straight Cartesian geometry. The interval for the difference defines boundaries of the form $X_1-X_2 = c$ (equivalently  $X_2=X_1-c$) which are lines on the $(X_1,X_2)$ plane which  have slope $1$. You designed your question around them passing through the indicated points, determining the location for each red line.

If you think of a concrete example (specifying the L's and R's) and work out what the interval is, you should be able verify that the points between the red lines are inside the interval.
